# Can I speed up this list generation in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have some code that creates a list with ascending numbers. If I put in a large number it takes some time to process. Is there any way to make this faster?

CODE:

```
def list_generator(starting_num, ending_num, behind_the_scenes_mode):
    if behind_the_scenes_mode:
        pass
    else:
        print("Generating Numbers.")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Generating Numbers..")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Generating Numbers...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Generating Numbers.")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Generating Numbers..")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Generating Numbers...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
    list_generated = [starting_num,]
    current_num = starting_num + 1
    while ending_num+1 != current_num:
        list_generated.append(current_num)
        current_num = current_num+1
    return list_generated
listgen_test = list_generator(1,15000,True)
print(listgen_test)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Easy ... remove all the needless `time.sleep()` and you speed if up by 15 seconds

Comment: `range(1, 15000)`? If you really need to, `list(range(1, 15000))`?

Comment: also:  `return list(range(starting_num, ending_num+1)` and be done - and why generate the list at all .. you can iterate a range(starting_num, ending_num+1) as easy as a list

Comment: @PatrickArtner the `time.sleep()`s are optional and can be disabled by setting the parameter `behind_the_scenes_mode` to `True`

Comment: @Sam The sleep(5) at the end is not - so it is always waiting 5 seconds. And for what you want to do a  `return list(range(start,end+1))` for reasonable numbers will run in milliseconds...

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the `sleep()` - especially the one at the end.
Remove the `print()`ing as well. IO costs time.
Do not loop. When looping you have for every single number:

- 1 check
- 1 increment
- 1 addition to a list - which might need to resize the underlying list and copy over data - not sure what python implementation you use and what underlying list structure is used. Resizing and copying list data may be costly - iteratively increasing a list is for sure more costly then allocating it on block and prefilling.

Generating number lists is fast:

```
import time

def nums(n):
    return list(range(n)) # don't loop and increase and test - simply create it

for i in range(0,10000000,1000):
    t = time.time()
    k = nums(i)
    t2 = time.time()
    print(i, t2-t)
```

Is currently running - I am up to 2.5 million and it takes about 0.06 seconds.

Output (use `timeit` instead if you want avg runtimes):

```
      0 0.0
   1000 0.0
...
   6000 0.000989675521850586
...
  16000 0.0009989738464355469
  17000 0.001001596450805664
...
  31000 0.0009992122650146484
  31000 0.0009992122650146484
  32000 0.0010020732879638672
  33000 0.0010006427764892578
...
2500000 0.06404614448547363
2501000 0.06404447555541992
...
4383000 0.13109230995178223
4384000 0.13109302520751953
...
5574000 0.1551225185394287
5575000 0.15309500694274902
...
6689000 0.19113492965698242
6690000 0.19213533401489258
...
7274000 0.20414447784423828
7275000 0.19313597679138184
...
9998000 0.259183406829834
9999000 0.26518726348876953
```